# Error using NRPE with ICINGA 2 - Unknown argument: -c

Tags: monitoring, nrpe, icinga, icinga2, icingaweb2

In order to migrate from icinga1 to icinga2, I'm basically concerned about the NRPE custom checks, till the time i tried to add just the basic memory check using NRPE.

With command line everything seems to be fine and perfect.

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.186.113.45 -p 5666 -c CheckMEM -a MaxWarn=80% MaxCrit=90% ShowAll=long type=physical
```

Output:

> OK: physical memory: Total: 64G - Used: 4.69G (7%) - Free: 59.3G (93%)|'physical memory %'=7%;80;90 'physical memory'=4.687G;51.174;57.57;0;63.967

But when I tried to apply the same with ICINGAweb2 it doesn't work well.

It simply gives me the error there as

> Unknown argument: -c

Below are the configurations for the command i tried to create as a beginner.

My command.conf file has certain part defined for the same specific check

```
object CheckCommand "nrpe-check-1arg" {
        import "plugin-check-command"
        command = [PluginDir + "/check_nrpe" ]
        arguments = {
        "-H" = "$host$"
        "-p" = "$port$"
        "-c" = "$check$"
        "-a" = "$argument$"
        }
}
```

and my hostfile.conf contains

```
object Host "RenamedHost" {
  address = "192.186.113.45"
  check_command = "hostalive"
  vars.os = "windows"
}
object Service "NRPE check load" {
        import "generic-service"
        host_name = "RenamedHost"
        check_command = "nrpe-check-1arg"
        vars.host = "132.186.119.45"
        vars.port = "5666"
        vars.check = "CheckMem"
        vars.argument = "MaxWarn=80% MaxCrit=90% ShowAll=long type=physical"
}
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: I'd advise to use the "nrpe" CheckCommand from the ITL and set the params accordingly. https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/agent-based-checks-addon#agent-based-checks-nrpe https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/plugin-check-commands#plugin-check-command-nrpe

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to pass the argument into nrpe.cfg as

```
vars.arguments = "80%!90%!long!physical"
```

And in command CheckMEM in remote machine you can specify the argument as

```
MaxWarn=$ARG1$ MaxCrit=$ARG2$ ShowAll=$ARG3$ type=$ARG4$
```